# How to create spanspec element based on grid element in the root element? -XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

How to create "spanspec" element based on "grid" based on grid element in the root element. I have create "colspec" based on grid element.
**Input XML**

```
<root>
    <grid/>
    <grid/>
    <grid/>
    <grid/>
</root>
```

**Expected output**

```
 <root>
   <colspec colnum="1" colname="col1"/>
   <colspec colnum="2" colname="col2"/>
   <colspec colnum="3" colname="col3"/>
   <colspec colnum="4" colname="col4"/>
   <spanspec namest="col1" nameend="col2" spanname="1TO2"/>
   <spanspec namest="col1" nameend="col3" spanname="1TO3"/>
   <spanspec namest="col1" nameend="col4" spanname="1TO4"/>
   <spanspec namest="col2" nameend="col3" spanname="2TO3"/>
   <spanspec namest="col2" nameend="col4" spanname="2TO4"/>
   <spanspec namest="col3" nameend="col4" spanname="3TO4"/>
</root>
```

**XSLT Code**

```
    <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:variable name="grid-count" select="count(//grid)"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="grid">
            <colspec colnum="{position()}" colname="{concat('col', position())}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="grid">
            <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$position to $grid-count - 1">
                <spanspec namest="{concat('col', $position)}" nameend="{concat('col', position()+1)}" spanname="{concat($position,'TO', position()+1)}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have solved**

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:variable name="grid-count" select="count(//grid)"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="grid">
            <colspec colnum="{position()}" colname="{concat('col', position())}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="grid">
            <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$position to $grid-count - 1">
                <spanspec namest="{concat('col', $position)}" nameend="{concat('col', $position + position())}" spanname="{concat($position,'TO', $position + position())}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```